# Number of extrema for given function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Given a function $f(x)=x^{2} + \ln(\cos(x))$. Find the number of its extrema.

I tried plotting the graph and found the local minimum at $x=0$ and two local maximum.

But am not able to proceed post it and how to get the stationary points for the given function so that in the extrema calculation we can ignore them.

Comment: Different yet important question : what is the domain of definition of your function ? There are infinitely many local maxima because of what you can notice by answering my question. However, if you restrict it to, say, $]-\pi/2,\pi/2[$, then it only has the one you talked about.

Comment: domain is -pi/2<x-2*pi*n<pi/2

Comment: And is $n$ arbitrary ? Please edit your question to show both more effort put into it and more context/clarification. **Hint :** What method could you apply to a *continuously-differentiable* function ?

Comment: n is arbitrary. sorry my bad i did not write the properly what i had tried. I got it now the domain is not restricted so the extrema values are infinite. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting by looking at the graph is a good approach but the problem with $f(x)$ is that its behaviour is so strange that a graphing program like Desmos might make it difficult to see what is really going on.

Have you tried finding $f'(x)$?

What do you know about the value of $f'(x)$ when $f(x)$ hits a max or min?

If you try this and rearrange the equation you find you will end up with the equation $2x=tan(x)$. Now, solving this equation would be very tricky, but luckily you don't have to! Think about the graphs of $y=2x$ and $y=tan(x)$. How many points of intersection do they have? What does this tell you about the number of extrema (max or min)?

Comment: Thank you. I tried calculating the derivative and plotted y=tan(x) and y=2x it will have infinite intersection points